# Do GIthub Sub-Directories Exist?

Tags: github

I am going back to school and I am hoping to store my projects, notes, etc. in git.  I am wondering if it is possible to create subdirectories so that my git does not get incredibly clustered.  for instance, I would like a git directory in the following structure:
/back_to_school/class_1.

However, it doesn't make sense for me to have my entire grad program be a single repo, so I'd like to have the repo comprise only class_1.

I recognize that I could just hard-code it myself, so it looks like /back_to_school_class_1, but that strikes me as clunky and likely to create clutter.

I did some quick googling but I'm not finding anything helpful.  Any tips or tricks would be greatly appreciated!